# JQuery how to get a total price?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following issue. When i have my shopping cart, i got multiple clubs in the cart. A user can be an admin for multiple clubs. My shopping cart returns something like this:

```
<h2>Club 1</h2>
<div>Price</div><div>50.00</div>

<h2>Club 2</h2>
<div>Price</div><div>49.00</div>

<h2>Club 3</h2>
<div>Price</div><div>10.00</div>
<div>Service payment</div><div>11.00</div>
```

I want to make a div below each club for a total with jQuery.

Why jQuery? Companys can select multiple options, there will be a value added and removed onClick()

Comment: A much easier approach would be to put all this in JSON, sum it there and build your html from it. I'd rather build UI from data than data from UI any day!

Comment: will you be able to change the html sligtly

Comment: Liath do u have a example code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6cXcr/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny works really smooth and lovely. Can you help me on one more thing. Sometimes i append another div.item to the list. It doesnt refresh on click. Can you help me out with it?

Comment: do you have a click handler.... can you share the code.. if you are dealing with dynamically added elements you may have to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var amount = 0;


    $('.factuur-post').click(function(){
        var club = $(this).attr('value');
        var item = '<div class="item"><div>Service</div><div>0.99</div></div>';

        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            amount += parseFloat(0.99);

            console.log('club id: ' + club)
            $(item).appendTo('#club' + club)
        } else {
            amount -= parseFloat(0.99);
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.factuur-post').click(function(){
        $('.total').remove();
        $('.club').each(function () {
          var total = 0;
          $(this).find('.item div:nth-child(2)').each(function () {
              total += parseInt($(this).text()) || 0
          });

          var $total = $('<div />', {
              'class': 'total',
              html: '<div><b>Total</b></div><div>' + total.toFixed(2) + '</div>'
          });
          $total.appendTo(this)
      })
    })
})
</script>
```